# onDraw() not working with micromax canvas phone

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

this is my on touch method .

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    drawView.setDetail(event.getX(),event.getY());
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    drawView.refreshDrawableState();
    rl.refreshDrawableState();
}
```

This is my canvas class.

```
public void setDetail(int x,int y)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
       paint.setStrokeWidth(3);        
        canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+300, y+500, paint);
   }
```

when i run my code in emulator it works fine, but when i m using it with micromax canvas, it is not working.